# How to determine multiple substrings of varying size from an API string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, substring, indexof

I have an API call that as part of the object returns something like this:

```
"aaps":"1.50U\/h 0.36U(0.18|0.18) -1.07 0g"
```

I would like to pull two substrings out of this but the size of the substrings will vary. For example, I would like one variable to be the substring of the number that precedes the ***second*** "U". But this value will be anywhere between 0.00 and 100.99. So I can't just count on using `indexof()`.

As well I would like another variable to be the substring of the number that precedes the "g". This variable will have a value of anywhere between 0 and 250 so the number of characters of the substring will vary.

Comment: You could try to jsonfy the string... then iterate through the resulting JSON

Comment: Why can't you use `indexOf()`? The value will change according to, well, the index of the character in the string. So `"1.50U".indexOf("U") === 4` and `"100.99U".indexOf("U") === 6`... To get the value, you'd just do `aaps.substring(0, aaps.indexOf("U"))`.

Comment: `indexOf` would still work. Cleaner way would be using a regex

Comment: Split the string, if the format is the same you can grab de numbers removing the last letter, ex: string.split()[1].split('U')[0] and string.split()[3].split('g')[0].

Comment: Sorry I forgot to clarify, I want the number before the second "U". so the "0.36" number. indexof wont work becuase it will return the number before the first "U", wont it?

Comment: @cramis1 So the number before the first "U" doesn't matter?

Comment: @Adam thats correct. I only want the number before the second U and before the g. Taking into account that the character length for each number is not fixed and can vary

Comment: @cramis1 Updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript's [`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) function is great for this.

```
var string = '1.50U\/h 0.36U(0.18|0.18) -1.07 0g';
var regex = /.+U.+(\d+\.\d{2})U.+(\d+)g/;
var match = regex.exec(string);
if (match) {
  console.log('Matches: ' + match[1] + ', ' + match[2]);
  // Matches: 0.36, 0
}
```

The regular expression captures the two numbers you need, and the `exec` function extracts them into an array. Here's what the regular expression means:

```
.+                         | Match one or more consecutive characters (any)
  U                        | Match the letter "U"
   .+                      | Match one or more consecutive characters (any)
     (                     | Capture the following:
      \d+                  |     One or more consecutive digits
         \.                |     The character "."
           \d{2}           |     Exactly 2 consecutive digits
                )          | End capture
                 U         | Match the letter "U"
                  .+       | Match one or more consecutive characters (any)
                    (\d+)  | Capture one or more consecutive digits
                         g | Match the letter "g"
```

Comment: I think you're right on here, but if OP is not familiar with regular expressions it's a mystery. The best regex answers I've seen break down and explain the parts of the regex.